# AlertDialogBuilder unsupported major.minor version 52

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm building an app with Android Studio.
At first time I have in my gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
}
```

Now I have added in my project, a card view so I have modified my gradle file like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

But now if I try to run my application, I have this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> android/app/AlertDialog$Builder : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android SDK Tools version `25.1.3` or higher - that one you have I see. Also check your `JAVA_HOME` to use JDK `1.8`. You can also enable JDK `1.8` in gradle by adding

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```